# Extract items in an arithmetic expression in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

If I have an arithmetic expression like x+y-12 / z in a string (c-style or otherwise) in c or c++, how can I extract one item at a time (including the operator)? There may or may not be a space in the expression and multiple digits are allowed for constants.

Comment: C or C++ - which is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input is simple you can start with something like this:

```
typedef struct token {
  int type;
  int ival;
  char sval[256];
  int  ssize;
} Token;

char *get_next_tok(char *buffer, Token *token) {
  char *p = buffer; while (isspace(*p)) p++; // trim
  if (my_isopchar(*p))     // checks -+*...
   p=my_get_op(p, token);  // a function to handle multi-char ops
  else if (isdigit(*p)) {
   token->ival=strtol(p, &p, 10);
   token->type=TK_CONST;
  }
  else if (isalpha(*p)) {
   while (isalpha(*p)) {
     token->sval[token->ssize++] = *p; p++;
   }
   token->type = TK_VAR;
  }
  return p;
}
```

Comment: what `while (isspace(*p)) p++;` do it?

Comment: it skips whitespace (tab, space, newline)

Comment: hum.. does not works for me. maybe because if myinput is `foo baa` for example, it does not remove any: tab,space or newline. When this condition `isspace(*p)` is tested in while loop, it return false because the first char is not a whitespace, so, the loop on string is not done. Then, instead of it, you can write:`char * buffer = " ba a kkk                k k $\0";
 char * newbuf = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
 assert(NULL != newbuf);
 char * p = buffer;
 char * ns = newbuf;
 
 while(*p) {
  if(!isspace(*p)) {
     *ns++ = *p++;
   }
  p++;
 }
 *ns ++ = '\0';

 printf("%s", newbuf);`

Comment: if the input is `foo baa` you will call this function twice, with "foo" and " baa". This function only parses a single token.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I found something that helped me here [C++ expression parser](http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_cpp/index.html).  @perreal Similar in concept to your way, I think

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Hard way: [Flex+Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). What you describe can, in fact, be quite easily implemented using regular expressions, or hand-written parsing. Think of what makes up your expression's individual tokens, and how code to extract the next token would look.

Answer (score 0):

There was a very nice [tutorial on Flipcode on implementing scripting engines](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Implementing_A_Scripting_Engine-Part_1_Overview.shtml). You can read a few of the first chapters.

Basically you need to implement a lexical analyzer which breaks the string into tokens (identifier / constant / operator) and from tokens you can create a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) or [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) e.g. by [recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or using a [LL parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) which is rather elegant if you are only interested in parsing arithmetic expressions.

Reverse Polish notation is then evaluated using stack-based interpreter or parse tree is evaluated using a recursive algorithm.

I have written a small [expression evaluation class](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/ExpEval_Test.zip) in C++ which supports simple expressions with variables.